# How to selectively import and export content between 2 Drupal websites?

Tags: backups

How to merge simple core content into from site a to site b. Content is created using core functionality and modules.

Let's say I have 2 Drupal 7 sites, both have same configuration and modules.

Site A has:

- 3 content types
- 3 taxonomies
- 3 articles

Site B has:

- 1 content types
- 1 taxonomies
- 1 articles

How do I append content of site B to site A?

I want the content from site A to be appended to site B. If I do backup migrate, the content of site A will be overwritten.

I've noticed that backup migrate can have manual selection of what to export, but it will overwrite destination right?

What is the best procedure for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could always write a couple of migration classes with the Migrate module, and hook up Site B as the datasource (the module would live in Site A).

You can do this by adding Site B's database credentials to the settings.php as another configuration, then calling on that in your script.

Here is an example of what a Migration class might look like:

```
class YourMigration extends Migration {
  public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);

    $query = Database::getConnection('connection_name', 'connection_key');
    // other query arguments to execute
  }
}
```

Where the `Database::getConnection` arguments are the names of the items in your `$databases` array in settings.php. With a working script, you can then write other scripts (or a cron job) to periodically run the migrate job.

Others will say to use Feeds, but I've always been a big Migrate fan (not Drupal2Drupal migrate module, the main Migrate module itself).

> I've noticed that backup migrate can have manual selection of what to
>   export, but it will overwrite destination right?

Pretty much. Site A would get wiped out. It also isn't as simple as moving MySQL data around, unless every data model in Site B is identical or exists in Site A even then its a fairly large technical challenge *not* to screw anything up. I would not do anything with SQL at this level - it needs to go through the API.

Comment: Thanks but....I'm not a developer...so this is way out of my league...isn't there a module or a simple way to to this in phpmyadmin or backup migrate?

Comment: A database sync would overwrite everything. You'd still be looking at custom MySQL scripts and it is way more complicated to do at that level because then you have to account for all the tables etc - there is more going on behind the scenes when Drupal creates a node. Dozens of tables can be involved depending on various factors, also all the revision tables too.

Comment: Feeds sounds like the only option for you then. https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds

Answer (score 0):

No code solution:

Use [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to import the data. But first, you'll need to [create a CSV of your data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssOF3nPgcfc). You can use [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export).

Now that you have a CSV, simply [import using feeds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXgjFRn7ty4&t=265s).